# Why is box-sizing:content-box being ignored on OS X WebKit browsers?

Tags: html, css

I'm setting a submit input to use the `content-box` value for the `box-sizing` property, e.g:

```
<style>input {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
</style>

<input type="submit" value="Button" />
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw4zt74L/)

But the height isn't being set on OS X Safari and Chrome due to it not following the `content-box` box model. It works fine OS X Firefox, and all Windows 8.1 browsers.

Is this a WebKit for OS X bug? Any workaround?

Comment: Does it work with the prefixed syntax?

Comment: Yep, no difference: http://jsfiddle.net/Lw4zt74L/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in WebKit browsers there's uneven support for this CSS3 directive. In order to make it work in these browser you need to add a new line with the -webkit- prefix. For a more thorough support, you may also wish to add yet another line with the -moz- prefix.

```
<style>
input {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Even adding the browser prefixes doesn't help, see http://jsfiddle.net/Lw4zt74L/2/. Also it's quite odd that it doesn't work on OS X, but it does work on Windows, despite my OS X browsers being up to date. But I guess my assumption that they'd have the same engine is probably wrong.

Comment: Though your comment on partial support does seem to be correct - http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing. Though that page still does say `content-box` should be fully supported. I've found that other elements work fine on these browsers, but submit inputs still don't.